# Add columns to extended `pandas.DataFrame` class

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, inheritance

I created a subclass of `pandas.DataFrame` to bundle a few functionalities:

```py
class ABT(pandas.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, data=None, ...):
        if data is None:
            ...
            data = DataFrame(..., tz='utc'))
        super(ABT, self).__init__(data)
```

I want to make a method that uses another DataFrame as a parameter and appends it to `ABT`. The question is: **How to join/merge/concat to `self`?**

```py
    def add_df(self, new_df):
        df_utc = new_df.tz_localize('CET', ambiguous='NaT').tz_convert('utc')

        ...

        self.merge(df_utc , how='left', inplace=True)
```

The above method does not work, but I hope there is a ncie way to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `inplace` keyword for [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Besides of this, you should read [Subclassing pandas datastructures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures). So you need something like this:

```
class ABT(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return ABT

    @property
    def _constructor_sliced(self):
        return pd.Series

    def add_df(self, new_df):
        return self.merge(new_df, how='left')



abt1 = ABT(df1)
abt2 = ABT(df2)
abt1 = abt1.add_df(abt2)
```

If you don't define the constructors, the result of `add_df()` will be of type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` instead of `ABT`.